# Why do I get a complex number when I use 'uitable' in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-table

I have data file included both type of numbers, real (fractions and integers) and complex. But when I use 'uitable' all data will turn to be complex (of course 0i as imaginary part). see the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydNLX.png)
Any recommendation on to get rid of those automatically appeared imaginary parts?

Comment: A real number is a complex number with zero imaginary part. They are not "random"

Comment: It is likely that if one number in the uitable is complex, they all must be. Probably a single array containing all the numbers.

Comment: From the `uitable` documentation: "Table UI components can accommodate a mixture of different data types **across the columns**." => You can have two columns containing a different data type, but for a single column, all the data have to be of the same type. So if one of your value in one column is `complex`, then MATLAB will automatically convert all the values for this column into the `complex` type. There is no trick that can change this behavior.

Comment: One possible workaround (I can't call it a trick as it's quite dirty), would be to split each column containing complex values into two columns. One column will contain the `real` part of the number (and will be populated completely), while the other column will contain the `imaginary` part (and for this column you could set some value to `empty` when the number only had a `real` component). It would be a lot of coding gymnastics just for a display tweek though ...

Comment: @Hoki Thanks a lot. very well explained, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a way around.

1.- Let's say that your data is for instance

```
c2 =   1.0e+02 *[  0.997200000000000 + 0.000000000000000i -2.980950000000000 - 2.615070000000000i  -5.201680000000000 - 5.166180000000001i -1.654660000000000 + 8.841020000000000i
 -7.100910000000000 - 0.214950000000000i  0.264990000000000 + 0.000000000000000i    -7.533630000000000 - 1.921760000000000i -9.006920000000001 + 0.000000000000000i
  7.060630000000000 + 0.000000000000000i -1.963840000000000 + 5.605040000000000i   -6.321850000000000 + 0.000000000000000i  8.054330000000000 + 1.504170000000000i
  2.441100000000000 + 8.001080000000000i -8.480670000000000 - 2.205220000000000i   -5.200950000000001 - 7.360539999999999i  8.895750000000000 - 8.804410000000001i]
```

then

```
hf1 = uifigure;
uit = uitable(hf1,'Data',c2);
```

[image]

when one tries casting or directly writing null imaginary part elements you are right, the table shown with uitable keeps `0i` on all elements of the table as soon as a single element has non null imaginary part. The following doesn't work

```
uit.Data(1,1)

uit.Data(1,1)=real(uit.Data(1,1))

uit.Data(1,1)=49

if imag(c2(:))==0 c(:)=real(c(:)); end
```

[image]

2.- Now let's convert the data fed to `uitable` to characters

```
c10={};
for k=1:1:numel(c2)
c10=[c10 strip(num2str(c2(k)))];

end
c10=reshape(c10,size(c2));

hf2=uifigure;
uit2=uitable(hf2,'Data',c10)
```

[image]

Now the resulting table produced with `uitable` complies with the requirement in your question, that table elements with null imaginary parts do not show `0i`.

Additional comment : I have used the following to generate random 4x4

```
simulating data
a=1e-3*randi([-1e6 1e6],1,16);
b=1e-3*randi([-1e6 1e6],1,16);
b(unique(randi([1 16],1,randi([4 12],1,1))))=0;
c=a+b*1j;
c2=reshape(c,[4 4])
```